# By-pass Same Origin Policy for IFrames

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, same-origin-policy

I am building a Node.JS server where third-party content is loaded via iFrame. It is unable to view sites such as reddit because of same origin restrictions. I know node has an http.get convenience method I could use to circumvent this. Could anyone give me a schematic or a plausible example code demonstrating how to render blocked content to an iframe in nodejs?

Thanks!

Comment: If the content itself detects being in an iFrame and the content requires Javascript in order to work or render, then there is nothing you can do to force it into an iFrame.  It's own Javascript will detect that it is framed and refuse to do its thing.  It's always possible to use your own server to fetch the content (the same way a browser fetches the content), but you can't use that method to make it work in an iframe if the content is built to detect that condition and refuse to work.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use an http request proxy piped to the response.